# Can't access array of objects returned from .net code in VBA

Tags: .net, com

I have created a COM library in c# which I am consuming from VBA in Excel.
My library has a property which returns an array of objects but when I try to access the elements of the array I get this compile error in VBA: "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment".

```
// C# property
Foo[] FooArray { get { return _fooArray; } }


' Client VBA code 
Dim obj as new Bar
Dim f as Foo
set f = obj.FooArray(0)
```

I tried returning an array of strings and saw the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim f as Foo
set f = obj.FooArray(0)
```

Four mistakes here.  FooArray is a property, not a function.  The property doesn't take an argument.  *Set* is incorrect, the property returns an array, not an object.  The type for `f` is wrong, the property returns an array, not a single Foo.  This ought to be closer:

```
Dim f As Foo()
f = obj.FooArray
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from the ambiguity in VB with the FooArray(0) syntax.  The parentheses can represent arguments of a Function/Sub call or an array indexer.

The solution is to explicitly declare an array, e.g. `fa()` as follows:

```
Dim f As Foo
Dim fa() As Foo
Dim b As New Bar

fa = b.FooArray
Set f = fa(0)
```